# POST data from Android to Web API returns 404

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to send data from my Android client as a POST request to my Web API Backend but it returns a 404 response code. Here's my code:

**Backend**:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/postcomment")]
public IHttpActionResult PostComment(string comment, string email, string actid)
{
       string status = CC.PostNewComment(comment, email, actid);
       return Ok(status);
}
```

**Android Code:**

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://MYWEBADDRESS.azure-mobile.net/api/postcomment");
String mobileServiceAppId = "AZURE_SERVICE_APP_ID";

try {

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("comment", comment));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", currEmail));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("actid", currActID));

        httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("ACCEPT", "application/json");
        httppost.setHeader("X-ZUMO-APPLICATION", mobileServiceAppId);

        UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs);
        httppost.setEntity(formEntity);

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

} 
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

However this returns a **404** Response code to my Android Client. Is my Code incorrect? Please point out the mistakes :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming, but to a WebService response/implementation.

Comment: Are you sure about your url ? Because (without playing Captain Obvious) 404 deals with not founded files/folder most of time..

Comment: @shkschneider waaah o.O It IS a programming related question lol. My code is probably wrong and Im asking for help from people who have already implemented the same code

Comment: @BastienViatge It has got to do something with my Backend mate, the URL is okay since I have used the same code for many other requests and they work

Comment: @Earthling waaah o.O Your backend is sending a valid `HTTP 404` response code, which is your problem, not your network-related code. Your backend sees your request as "bad" and returns `404 Not Found`, that's it. Check your url and/or backend, but there is nothing we can guess to "fix" your "issue" mate...

Comment: 'to my Web API Backend but it returns a 404 response code. '. No not your backend returns that but the webserver. Your url is not ok so the webserver cannot even find your backend.

Comment: Why are you not using the Mobile Services API to invoke your API? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-android-call-custom-api/

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Oh wow I didn't know about that mate. I'll do that now. Btw if you are part of the azure team, I need to let you know that it's very difficult to find the 'right' tutorials since right now it's a big cluster and finding a tutorial is very difficult :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We share your opinion and are working with the doc team to make it easier to find things. I tend to just use a search engine "azure mobile services [android/ios] [topic]" :P

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Brilliant! :) Also I was wondering.. is it possible to request authentication tokens from android without using the Azure Libraries? As in, simply request the token by JSON instead of using the MobileServiceClient?

Comment: It's entirely possible. Our clients are just speaking plain old HTTPS. You'll have to take a look at the way our client works to make sure you're doing it correctly. The code is all on github if you want to try. There is a REST API guide on MSDN. Is there a reason you don't want to use the client?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson-MSFT Good to hear, mate. Thanks so much. No no there's nothing wrong with the client :) I'm just used to doing it this way and I thought it would be quicker to stick to it :)

Comment: We try to make things easier. :) If you ever find that it's not, let us know - http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-apps-formerly-mobile-services

Comment: Sorry to lengthen this post but is it also possible to get a success or failure response from the backend along with the data it sends through the JSON? As in, "Status":"Success" or "Status":"Fail" along with the data? :) @ChrisAnderson-MSFT

Comment: If you're writing a custom API, you can do anything you want. Just change the object you return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed this by properly setting up my backend to accept the parameters sent by the android client. The problem was with my backend, not my client.

Here's my backend:

```
[Route("api/postcomment")]
public IHttpActionResult PostComment([FromBody] CommentViewModel model)
{
       string comment = model.Comment;
       //Do your processing
       return Ok(return_something);
}

public class CommentViewModel
{
        public string Comment { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Actid { get; set; }
}
```

I used the [FromBody] to force the method to read the request body and I used a model to get the values passed by the client. The method automatically gets the values from the request and sets them to the model making it very easy.

**MAKE SURE that your android client is properly passing your parameters with a correct POST code.**