# Sending http post to dot net webapi

Tags: java, android, http, post, asp.net-web-api

I have this Problem

> **Working With Get**

I wanted to send an http post

Here Is My android Class And Request method

```
    public static String readUrl(String url, ArrayList<NameValuePair> params) {
    try {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);

        if (params != null) {
            method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

        }

        HttpResponse response = client.execute(method);

        InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
        String result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);

        return result;
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

and this is request Code

```
                                ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("region","1"));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area","1"));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sector","1"));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("address",edtReqAddres.getText().toString()));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile",edtMobileNumber.getText().toString()));

                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username","test"));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", edtSubject.getText().toString()));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("compid","0"));
                                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("geo","1"));


                                text = webservice.readUrl("http://192.168.1.102:81/api/products", params);
```

And Also This is my Result 
:(

> {"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://192.168.1.102:81/api/products'."}

This is my WebApi (DotNet)

```
    [System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
    public string GetProductById(int region, int area, int sector, string address, string mobile, string username, string message, int compid, string geo)
    {
      fddService.mobService service=new mobService();
      return service.NewMessage(region, area, sector, address, mobile, "", message, compid, "");
    }
```

Comment: You haven't configured your server to handle `/api/products` request.

Comment: Hmm I'm new in web api what do you mean @ColinGillespie please Explain More

Comment: I Can make it By Get @ColinGillespie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally i reached the answer 
On the **Client Side** You should add this line to your code to set the defult content type

```
httpPost.addHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

On the **backend Server (WebApi)** should create a **ModelView** to send the params and also add `[FromBody]` at the begining of the input params like this

```
public string postreq([FromBody] RequestViewModel model)
{
    fddService.mobService service = new mobService();
    if (model.geo == "1")
        return service.NewMessage(Convert.ToInt32(model.region), Convert.ToInt32(model.area),
            Convert.ToInt32(model.sector), model.address, model.mobile, "", model.message, Convert.ToInt32(model.compid), "");
    else
        return service.NewMessage(Convert.ToInt32(model.region), Convert.ToInt32(model.area),
            Convert.ToInt32(model.sector), model.address, model.mobile, "", model.message, Convert.ToInt32(model.compid), model.geo);
}
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public string region { get; set; }
    public string area { get; set; }
    public string sector { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
    public string mobile { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string compid { get; set; }
    public string geo { get; set; }
}
```

if you got this `{"Message":"An error has occurred."}` :

> MAKE SURE that your android client is properly passing your parameters with a correct POST code.

thanks to : Earthling 
[POST data from Android to Web API returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478149/post-data-from-android-to-web-api-returns-404)

Answer (score 2):

If you use ASP.NET WebAPI in Visual Studio, you can add a new Web API Controller Class (v2.1), then you will have the following default code:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
    {
        // GET api/<controller>
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/<controller>/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/<controller>/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

Then, let's assume you have a DTO class such as **Product**, you can customize your Web API as the following:

```
        // POST: api/Products
        [ResponseType(typeof(Product))]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostProduct(Product product)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Products.Add(product);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.Id }, product);
        }
```

You will find more information at [Learn About ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: that's Perfect @BNK Thanks Alot

Comment: But You Know I Wanted To Make My Method Only Accept Post Requests @BNK Is [FromBody] Enough for that ?

Comment: `Post` is already POST only, FromBody is just a body of POST :)

Comment: If you mean that .../api/products accepts POST only, you can remove Get() method

Comment: I LOVE You :D @BNK Just Needed to rename it And start the Method Name By Post Word !!