# HttpPost [FromBody] parameter always null

Tags: java, android, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

**Asp.net webApi 2**
[FromBody] parameter always null. (HttpGet method works fine.)
if i try to pass json then and recieve `([FromBody] string param)` then i got null in param.
if i try to get it in custom class object then object is not null but all properties found null.
**I did try to call post method from android and also from fiddler** but faild to identify the problem.
[WebApi withfiddler example](http://www.devcurry.com/2013/03/debugging-your-aspnet-web-apis-with.html) i had download this source code and try it using fidler but this code also doesn't work.
**Please help where is the issue is there something wrong with my visual studio or i am doing wrong in my code. thanx in advance.**

**here is api method**

```
[Route("Signup")]
    [HttpPost]
    public string SignUp([FromBody] User user)
    {
        user.ip = ClientIp;
        if (UserManager.SaveUser(user))
        {
            return "succeed";
        }
        else
        {
            return "failed";
        }

    }
```

if method recieve parameter like in above code then object properties are null but object is not null.

```
public string SignUp([FromBody] string param)
```

if it recieves string then it always found null.

**here is android call**

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpEntity httpEntity = null;
        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        StringEntity se=new StringEntity(params.toString());
        // Checking http request method type
        if (method == Constants.MethodInfo.POST) {
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            // adding post para[![try to post using Fiddler][2]][2]ms
            if (se != null) {

                httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(params.toString(),HTTP.UTF_8));
                httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            }

            httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: My best guess is that your parameters are not being sent. How in android you set the parameters? What is params.toString()? I'm not an android developer but that seems wrong to me. See an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31478149/post-data-from-android-to-web-api-returns-404

Comment: param is a json object. i just convert my custom class object ino json using gson library. i did debug param has values as i set.

Comment: i also try fiddler but i can't get values in parameter of aps.net web api method.

Comment: Have you tried something like: MultipartEntity multipartEntity = new MultipartEntity();    
multipartEntity.addPart("data", new StringBody(jsonObject.toString()));
httpPost.setEntity(multipartEntity);